# Hibernate SQL Reference Exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Today i was trying to add Customer to database using Hibernate Annotation but i dont know why i am facing a reference Problem with a table !

Please read the Exception below

> ERROR: Referential integrity constraint violation:
>
> "FKOFMCQE0O4K2TFOXB308SKTMQ3: PUBLIC.CUSTOMER FOREIGN
>   KEY(CUS_BILLINGADDRESSID) REFERENCES
>   PUBLIC.CUSTOMERBILLINGADDRESS(CUS_BILLINGADDRESSID) ('CBA00001')"; SQL
>   statement:
>       update Customer set cus_emailid=?, cus_mobileno=?, cus_name=?, cus_billingaddressid=?, cus_cartid=?, cus_loginid=?,
>   cus_shippingaddressid=? where cus_id=? [23506-193]
>       Apr 01, 2017 7:09:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
>       INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>       Apr 01, 2017 7:09:57 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl
>   mapManagedFlushFailure
>       ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement]
>       Apr 01, 2017 7:09:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>       SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/TechNXT] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement] with root cause
>       org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKOFMCQE0O4K2TFOXB308SKTMQ3: PUBLIC.CUSTOMER FOREIGN
>   KEY(CUS_BILLINGADDRESSID) REFERENCES
>   PUBLIC.CUSTOMERBILLINGADDRESS(CUS_BILLINGADDRESSID) ('CBA00001')"; SQL
>   statement:
>       update Customer set cus_emailid=?, cus_mobileno=?, cus_name=?, cus_billingaddressid=?, cus_cartid=?, cus_loginid=?,
>   cus_shippingaddressid=? where cus_id=? [23506-192]
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
>         at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:372)
>         at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:314)
>         at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:967)
>         at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:985)
>         at org.h2.command.dml.Update.update(Update.java:151)
>         at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
>         at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
>         at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:344)
>         at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:158)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Here is my Two model Tables 
 NOTE : i have generated getters and Setters but not posting so making as small as possible 
1. Customer table which has a references of the other table

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String cus_id;
    private String cus_name;
    private String cus_emailid;
    private String cus_mobileno;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="cus_loginid")
    private CustomerDetails customerdetails;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="cus_billingaddressid")
    private CustomerBillingAddress customerbillingaddress;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="cus_shippingaddressid")
    private CustomerShippingAddress customershippingaddress;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="cus_cartid")
    private CustomerCart customercart;
```

2. My Customer Billing Address Model

   @Entity
   public class CustomerBillingAddress {

   ```
   @Id
   private String cus_billingaddressid;
   private String cus_houseno;
   private String cus_street;
   private String cus_area;
   private String cus_city;
   private String cus_state;
   private String cus_country;
   private String cus_pincode;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy="customerbillingaddress")
   private Customer customer;
   ```

Similarly Other Models

And Finally My DAO method which add the Customer to db

here is the code !

```
@Transactional
    public String addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        System.out.println("CustomerDao -TechNXT\n");
        Session ses = sf.openSession();
        customer.setCus_id(generateCustomerid());
        customer.setCustomerbillingaddress(new CustomerBillingAddress());
        customer.setCustomershippingaddress(new CustomerShippingAddress());
        customer.setCustomercart(new CustomerCart());
        customer.getCustomerdetails().setCus_loginid(generateCustomerLoginid());
        customer.getCustomerbillingaddress().setCus_billingaddressid(generateCustomerBillingid());
        customer.getCustomershippingaddress().setCus_shippingaddressid(generateCustomershippingid());
        customer.getCustomercart().setCus_cartid(generateCustomerCartid());
        customer.getCustomerdetails().setCus_isenabled(true);
        customer.getCustomerdetails().setCus_role("ROLE_USER");
        Transaction tr = ses.beginTransaction();

        ses.save(customer);
        tr.commit();
        ses.close();
        return customer.getCustomerdetails().getCus_loginid();
    }
```

Well i have being trying stuffs since 3hrs but failed to get a solution of it !!
Sorry for taking your precious time.
and Thanking you in advance for helping me !

Comment: Have you tried Cascadetype.All on CustomerBillingAddress field in Customer?

Comment: You should Google Hibernate Cascadetype and read up on it e.g. http://www.dineshonjava.com/p/cascadetypes-and-other-things.html?m=1

Comment: I answered the other question. CascadeType.ALL includes all cascades which means that when you remove a Customer object the objects in the fields get removed too. If you just want a couple of the types use `@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})  e.g.
`

Comment: @JackFlamp Thank you so much ! sir where can i follow you :)

Answer (score -1):

can you mark the @Table annontation on your class

like

`@Table(name ="Customer")`

Comment: sure , i will update my model with the table Annotation ty :)